# Unable to search for the SQL keyword BETWEEN

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, search

When I search for the word "BETWEEN" (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=between) I get the following error message:

> Please enter some text to search for in the upper right!

I imagine this is because of keyword filtering, is this required? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I have found a workaround using google and querying "site:stackoverflow.com between"

Comment: Whatever you do, don't search for "DR*P T*BLE"!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/why-cant-you-search-for-where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is a stop word and will not be searched. Use more unique words in your search..

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001186.html