# Why can't you search for "where"?

Tags: bug, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to search for the SQL keyword BETWEEN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/unable-to-search-for-the-sql-keyword-between)

Was trying to find an answer I saw a few days back where some gave a Linq example.  I entered ".Where(" as my search term and it comes back with the error message: "Please enter some text to search for in the upper right!"

same thing happens with the following terms:
.Where
Where

Comment: The same happens when you search for "from"

Comment: as well as "to"

Comment: why not "select" then?

Comment: @ChrisF: What harm is select without from?

Comment: But not "select" because is not on the stop list - http://www.sugarcrm.com/wiki/index.php?title=Overview%5Fof%5FFull%5FText%5FStop%5FWords

Comment: @RichB - I realised that after I double checked the link you provided. So the moral is think first then type.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/unable-to-search-for-the-sql-keyword-between

Comment: Search definitely doesn't like you searching for "--", http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is a stop word.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this is a stop word and will not be searched. Use more unique words in your search..

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001186.html

Comment: That's the problem.  The only part of the question I remember is that it had some Linq code including a .Where(

Comment: And interesting that you link to your own article where you basically question whether stop words are even necessary.

Comment: remember, Google, like God, is Always There..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like SQL keywords are being filtered out for safety.

Comment: I don't think that would be necessary