# Avoid keyword elimination in search

Tags: feature-request, search

If you search for `delete this`, the second keyword doesn't appear in the search results. I suspect this is due to typical search optimizations, but depending on the context, it might be of interest.

I couldn't find any way to force the keyword to be taken into account (usually with quotes or a plus).

Does such a syntax exist? I think the search engine should emphasize that the keyword has been removed. I know this is a really specific search, but I'm sure we can find other examples (especially in the programming area).

Comment: And yes, I've read http://stackoverflow.com/search. The "+" doesn't work here.

Comment: It seems "this" is a [stop word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words).  It doesn't answer your question, but it seems to be the post you were looking for:  [Is it safe to delete this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550189/is-it-safe-to-delete-this)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/unable-to-search-for-the-sql-keyword-between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it's the time to use Google for this case

> [site:stackoverflow.com "delete this"](http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20%22delete%20this%22)

Comment: That's a calid workaround so I'll put it as solved. Still, this is not the answer to the original question.

Comment: @Warren, you don't have to accept it for that case I think.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax: `"delete this"` works just fine for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22delete+this%22

As does the syntax `"delete" "this"`:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22delete%22+%22this%22

In neither case is the word "this" is filtered from the results.

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't for me. `this` never shows up in the search results.

Comment: @Warren: You don't get questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303608/delete-this-in-constructor), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this), and [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550189/is-it-safe-to-delete-this) in the search results? Those are all about `delete this`.

Comment: Yes, they appear, but I have to scroll down a lot. There are much less popular/pertinent questions before. Since `this` is never highlighted, I highly suspect they only appear because of `detect`.