# Searching for entries with "with" in the title

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to search for the SQL keyword BETWEEN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/unable-to-search-for-the-sql-keyword-between)

I'm trying to do searches in StackOverflow for the Python 'with' statement.

The search engine keeps returning '0' matches.

In the search bar I've tried:

with
'with'
"with"
[python] 'with'
[python] title: 'with'

all with varying levels of failure.

If I begin to create a question concerning 'with', Stack Overflow helpfully suggests "similar" questions, which include several regarding the Python 'with' statement.

How can I look for Stack Overflow questions regarding the statement 'with'?