# Search returns no matches for specific terms

Tags: bug, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to search for the SQL keyword BETWEEN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/unable-to-search-for-the-sql-keyword-between)

I've found a bug in the search engine. It is very reproducible.

- Go to [EL&U SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- Search for *[that that](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=that%20that)*. The search engine says that there are no matches. I don't know why it returns no results, but the engine works with other phrases such as *[wind wind](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wind%20wind&submit=search)*. The [Google Search for *that that*](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:english.stackexchange.com/questions%20that%20that), however, finds many results on the site.

[image: Your search returned no matches.]

So for some reason, the search engine is not returning any matches for this search, but works perfectly fine with other searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, although a more meaningful error message would be welcome.

*That* is a very common word in the English language. Therefore, it's considered a [stop word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) and filtered out of your search.

Since your search only consists of stop words, you basically search for an empty string.

Comment: Is there any work around?

Comment: Besides using Google, none that I know of.

Comment: Is there a list of stop words used on SE?

Comment: I can't find it on Meta. That probably means no.